# Remove synonym [jq] -> [jquery]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) actually exists (now):

> jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/json-select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq) cannot be tagged with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) since it's automatically converted to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

I suggest to remove the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) synonym for [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

Comment: It was created in the first place because users used it for jQuery, right? If synonym will be deleted, don't we risk that it will be used for both jQuery and real jq? It would create some mess. Just saying, upvoted anyway.

Comment: @Mołot Let's wait and see - and add a helpful tag summary including: "jq is a lightweight JSON processor. If you're asking about jQuery, use the jQuery tag instead."

Comment: Perhaps the tag for the `jq` JSON parser should be `jq-json-parser` to completely eliminate the possible ambiguity caused by users with poor tagging skills.

Comment: @Charles Good idea. Please add it as neither myself nor Felix can (too low rep).

Comment: How about 'jq-command'? We do not really have anything like 'sed-text-parser' or 'rails-dynamic-web-framework' now, do we?